# Python - Why does __str__ want something returned when it called? I have print functions inside of __str__

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, return

I am building a simple class in python. I have defined my own `__str__` method that should work nicely when I call print on an instance of the class. When I create an instance of the class and call `print` on it I get an error:

```
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

I understand this error, it is telling me the function did not return anything (it returned `None`)

```
class Car(object):

    def __init__(self, typ, make, model, color, year, miles):
        self.typ = typ
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.color = color.lower()
        self.year = year
        self.miles = miles

    def __str__(self):
        print('Vehicle Type: ' + str(self.typ))
        print('Make: ' + str(self.make))
        print('Model: ' + str(self.model))
        print('Year: ' + str(self.year))
        print('Miles: ' + str(self.miles))
        #return ''  # I can avoid getting an error if I un-comment this line

bmw = Car('SUV', 'BMW', 'X5', 'silver', 2003, 12030)
print bmw
```

As you can see my `__str__` function has all the print statements that I want. I have no need for it to return anything. This is the output I want.

```
Vehicle Type: SUV
Make: BMW
Model: X5
Year: 2003
Miles: 12030
```

How can I get this output?
I have tried this to avoid getting an error printed but the erro still comes up:

```
def __str__(self):
    try:
        print('Vehicle Type: ' + str(self.typ))
        print('Make: ' + str(self.make))
        print('Model: ' + str(self.model))
        print('Year: ' + str(self.year))
        print('Miles: ' + str(self.miles))
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: `__str__` is for `str` is for getting a textual representation. You *don't* always want to print this representation, you want it to *return* this representation so one can do other things with it: Embed it into other text, write it to a file (without redirecting stdout), do string manipulation to it, store it in a data structure for later use, etc. And it *should* be printed it, that's as simple as `print(vehicle)` because `print` calls `str`. Returning the textual representation is far more general than printing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the [`__str__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) docs,

> Called by the str() built-in function and by the print statement to
>   compute the “informal” string representation of an object. This
>   differs from **repr**() in that it does not have to be a valid Python
>   expression: a more convenient or concise representation may be used
>   instead. **The return value must be a string object.**

So, the value returned by `__str__` must be a string, in your case, you are returning nothing, so Python returns `None`, by default.

You can get the desired output, by simply changing the `__str__` function, like this

```
def __str__(self):
    return "Vehicle Type: {}\nMake: {}\nModel: {}\nYear: {}\nMiles: {}" \
        .format(self.typ, self.make, self.model, self.year, self.miles)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a big string and make the function return it:

```
def __str__(self):
    result = 'Vehicle Type: ' + str(self.typ) # just the start, append everything else to this string
    return result
```

The **str** method is used for the creation of the string to print, not for the printing itself. This is done implicitly when you call str(object).

Answer (score 1):

[`__str__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method usually returns a human readable string representation of the object. You should build a string in the `__str__` method and print it later:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "Vehicle type: {self.typ}\nMake: {self.make}\nModel: {self.model}\nYear: {self.year}\nMiles: {self.miles}".format(self=self)

bmw = Car('SUV', 'BMW', 'X5', 'silver', 2003, 12030)
print str(bmw)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that's how `__str__`, which you are overriding, is defined.  If you don't want a string returned, use a different method.

Answer (score 0):

You *must* return a string from `__str__` because you are overriding a method in the base class of your custom class, therefore you need to respect its contract, or signature, or whatever you want to call the constrain that prescribes `__str__` to accept no parameters and return a string object.

Besides this simple object-oriented concept, that would be nice if you grasped on yourself before bragging about having this or that need to return anything from anywhere, there is another, basic programming concept, that you should start getting familiar with: the separation of model logic from I/O. Never, ever, pollute some model class with `print` statements: let it holds data and behavior properly related to that data, and allow user interface tasks, such as printing something on screen, to be performed by some other entity in your application.

Answer (score 0):

While many of the answers given here are correct, this is what is needed.
Remember, Slybookz does not have your back.

```
   def __str__(self):
      return "Year: " + str(self.year_made) + ", VIN: " + str(self.car_vin)
```